# Grub rescue after windows install

Tags: windows, swap, grubrescue

**Disaster, Please, Help ASAP.**

I had a dual boot on my pc with windows xp and lubuntu linux. Then recently i had some windows errors and decided to install windows 8 instead of xp.

So after i reinstalled windows i installed grub, in order to boot my old linux like this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt /dev/sda5
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
```

And this is what fdisk -l shows:

```
device     boot   id   system
/dev/sda1  *      7     HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2         7     HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3         f     w95 Ext'd (LBA) <- used to be D: disk, not yet mounted
/dev/sda5         83    Linux
/dev/sda6         82    Linux swap / Solaris
```

And this is what i get when i boot linux:

> begin: running /scripts/local-premount ... resume: libgcrypt version:
>   1.5.0 resume: could not stat resume device file '/dev/sda7' 
>   and it says press enter to start system or something like that.

My guess is that something went wrong with swap partition. I am not experienced linux user, so please provide as detailed instructions as possible.

Comment: did you use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to reinstall grub?

Comment: I fixed it: sudo apt-get purge hibernate, i cant answer my question yet becaus of low reputation )))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the case with:
   `sudo apt-get purge hibernate`